# Hash a Select SQLAlchemy query

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy query that I build, such as :

```
query_one = User.query.filter(User.id == 1)  # Note that I don't call .first() or .all() as I want the "select" instance.
```

I want to store this Select query in such a way that I can retrieve it by having the same query :

```
stored_queries = {}
stored_queries[hash(query_one)] = query_one

# ... later on:
query_two = User.query.filter(User.id == 1)

if hash(query_two) in stored_queries:
    # Execute custom code because it's the same query
```

Of course, `hash` in that case does not work, but is there a SQLAlchemy method that works in the same way?

I thought of `str(query_one)`, but that query only consider the request, without the value. I need both.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the query to get access to the parameters, and use those as part of your key:

```
def query_key(query):
    statement = query_one.statement.compile()
    return str(statement), str(statement.params)

query_key(query_one)
('SELECT user.id, ... FROM user WHERE user.id = :id_1', "{'id_1': 1}")
```

See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TableClause.compile